# Create a Linux image

Tags: rhel, images

Good Afternoon Everyone!

First off I am a Linux nooby, been doing windows administration for several years but recently our company has decided to start deploying RHEL servers. Anyways I have spent the last 4 days creating a STIG compliant RHEL system that is customized just the way we need it and now I want to clone it 3 more times and use all 4 on the same network. I know with windows each of the systems could be cloned and then had to be sysprepped before they would work properly. How does it work with Linux?

Before people start, yes I have Googled and found a dozen ways to accomplish similar tasks (clone exact system using Clonezilla/Symantec ghost, create automated installation using kickstarter) but none of them are what I need. Any help is deeply appreciated.'

OS: RHEL 6.2

Comment: With the adoption of a config management, imaging for OS deployment has been a pretty dead concept for a while, even amongst Windows admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you will be cloning them with something like VMware?

As a finishing touch on your STIG'd prototype VM, remove the lines `HWADDR` and `UUID` from any of the `ifcfg-*` files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.

1. Shut down the prototype VM.
2. Clone the VM, but do not automatically start the new VM.
3. Turn off the network adapters of the new VM.
4. Start the new VM.
5. Log in via the console and execute `rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. (This file will come back on reboot.)
6. Change `HOSTNAME` in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.
7. Using static IP addressing? Edit the right `ifcfg-*` file in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.
8. Shutdown the new VM.
9. Turn on the network adapters.
10. Turn on the new VM and enjoy!

If at any point you have to choose to use new MAC addresses, do so. :)

Comment: Will it work for a non VM environment? Like image of a physical machine installed on another physical machine?

Comment: @Rahatur Yes. Keep the clone unplugged from the network until Step 8.

Comment: If I want to clone a physical machine then do I need to remove HWADDR and UUID?

Comment: Yes, because the hardware is changing.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do any sort of sysprep equivalent prior to cloning, but you do need to change the hostname and IP address of each machine after cloning. You may need to make other changes to software you have installed, but as far as the OS is concerned, just change the IP and hostname and you're good to go.

Having said that, and not knowing your specific environment, I would encourage you to take another look at kickstarting machines or at some sort of configuration management system like Puppet and avoid cloning machines. Cloning machines leads to a lot more time spent debugging problems down the road, especially if you start making use of a Spacewalk or RHN type update service.