# Clone and restore a Opensuse linux on another physical machine

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse, clonezilla, clone

I have a Opensuse Linux installed and all application/database configured. This Linux has no GUI, only command prompt. Now we want to create an image of this installation so that we can set it up on another machine or restore in case of a disaster.

I have read the steps discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213106/407276). But it is really confusing as it was discussed for VMs. I Was wondering if anyone can outline some steps with commands to clone the entire OS as an .iso image so that I can install it on another machine too.

Answer (score 0):

There a [document on suse](https://software.opensuse.org/package/rear) to get prepared for future disaster which is sufficient for to backup and reuse the data. If it doesn't fits you then there are few software I know and they are named as:

- system back
- clonezilla
- timeshift

I had personally tried systemback for my mint machine and work fine. The thing you have to realize is that you cannot make the install-able live cd of your current system(this takes bit more effort and internal knowledge) because the installed system is shrinked for your specific hardware and even the hardware is same the things like uuid table will make frustrating. (Although system back was close to get this result. I was able to create a bootable iso). And another thing is that it gets more difficult when your filesystem grows.
**Final Suggestion**

> Use the regular backup method as mentioned in offical documents by distro provider to keep everything safe and the given method on documentation will of-course meet your needs.

Comment: Documents by distro provider is a vast one and covers lots of areas. Suitable for system admins. For sure that is the best way. But I was looking for a way to install the system on a new machine. Will try the system back.